# How can I generate a rolling metric like this in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that initially contains two columns, Home, which is 1 if a game was player at home, else 0, and PTS, which records the number of points a player scored in a given game. I want to end up with a third column, a rolling metric that represents how sensitive a player is to playing at home. I'll calculate this as follows:

Home Sensitivity = (Average PTS Home - Average PTS Away)/Average PTS

I did this successfully in the following code, but it felt cumbersome, as I created many columns I didn't need in the end. How can I solve this problem more directly?

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Home':[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0], 'PTS':[11, 10, 12, 11, 13, 12, 14, 12]})

df.loc[testDF['Home'] == 1, 'Home PTS'] = df['PTS']
df.loc[testDF['Home'] == 0, 'Away PTS'] = df['PTS']
df['Home PTS'] = df['Home PTS'].fillna(0)
df['Away PTS'] = df['Away PTS'].fillna(0)
df['Home Sum'] = df['Home PTS'].expanding(min_periods=1).sum()
df['Away Sum'] = df['Away PTS'].expanding(min_periods=1).sum()
df['Home Count']=df['Home'].expanding().sum()
df['Index']=df.index+1
df['Away Count']=df['Index']-df['Home Count']
df['Home Average']=df['Home Sum']/df['Home Count']
df['Away Average']=df['Away Sum']/df['Away Count']
df['Average']=df['PTS'].expanding().mean()
df['Metric']=(df['Home Average']-df['Away Average'])/df['Average']
```

Comment: How many rows do you want to include in *window*? ...http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions

Comment: All the prior rows in the dataframe. My understanding is that using expanding is like using rolling with my desired window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive way to do it: take increasingly larger slices of the DataFrame in a loop; do the math on each slice and store it in a list; assign the list to a new column of the DataFrame (using your testDF):

```
df = tesdDF
sens = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    d = df[:i]
    mean_pts = d.PTS.mean()
    home = d[d.Home == 1].PTS.mean()
    away = d[d.Home == 0].PTS.mean()
    #print(home, away, (home - away) / mean_pts)
    sens.append((home - away) / mean_pts)

df['sens'] = sens

>>> df
   Home  PTS      sens
0     1   11       NaN
1     0   10       NaN
2     1   12  0.095238
3     0   11  0.136364
4     1   13  0.090909
5     0   12  0.131579
6     1   14  0.086957
7     0   12  0.126506
```

---

Using DataFrame.expanding():  Not quite there yet ...

```
>>> mean_pts = df.PTS.expanding(1).mean()
>>> away = df[df['Home'] == 0].PTS.expanding(1).mean()
>>> home = df[df['Home'] == 1].PTS.expanding(1).mean()
>>> 

>>> home
0    11.0
2    11.5
4    12.0
6    12.5
Name: PTS, dtype: float64
>>> away
1    10.00
3    10.50
5    11.00
7    11.25
Name: PTS, dtype: float64
>>> mean_pts
0    11.000000
1    10.500000
2    11.000000
3    11.000000
4    11.400000
5    11.500000
6    11.857143
7    11.875000
Name: PTS, dtype: float64
>>>
```

To do the math will require more manipulation.
You cannot get the difference between `home` and `away` directly because the indices are different - but you can do ...

```
>>> home.values - away.values
array([ 1.  ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  1.25])
>>>
```

Also `home` and `away` only have four rows and `mean_pts` has eight.

---

I tried `.expanding(1).apply()` with the following function and didn't get what I expected, `expanding` doesn't pass both columns to the function, it appears to pass one column then the other; so I punted...

```
def f(thing):
    print(thing, '***')
    return thing.mean()

>>> df.expanding(1).apply(f)
[ 1.] ***
[ 1.  0.] ***
[ 1.  0.  1.] ***
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.] ***
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.] ***
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.] ***
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.] ***
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.] ***
[ 11.] ***
[ 11.  10.] ***
[ 11.  10.  12.] ***
[ 11.  10.  12.  11.] ***
[ 11.  10.  12.  11.  13.] ***
[ 11.  10.  12.  11.  13.  12.] ***
[ 11.  10.  12.  11.  13.  12.  14.] ***
[ 11.  10.  12.  11.  13.  12.  14.  12.] ***
```

Comment: This looks like it works, and is clearly more direct than what I did. I was hoping to do it more efficiently with Pandas (maybe expanding.apply?), but if no one comes up with such a solution, I'll be sure to accept this answer!